# Javascript has strange while loop outcome

Tags: javascript

I've had a couple strange but undesirable outcomes in a while loop that I've written in JS. I basically have created a loop inside of a function that takes user input and places it in an array. The loop can end when the user has entered the sentinel value. Some of the things I've tried include:

- When I change the statement `while (i < arrLength)` to `while (i <= arrLength)` I will only get a single prompt for name and then the loop will end. When I keep it the way it was, nothing will happen.
- When I move the if statement below the two prompts I will only get a prompt for name and grade and then the loop will end.

I can't quite understand why this is happening and why I'm not getting a desired result. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Here is the loop (full code at bottom):

```
//function to get student info
function getStudentInfo(arr){
  let i = 0;
  const arrLength = arr.length;
  while (i <= arrLength) {
    if(arr.name === "???"){
      break;
    }
    arr[i].name = prompt("Enter student name: ");
    arr[i].grade = parseInt(prompt("Enter student grade: "));
    i++;
  }
}
```

```js
class Student {
  //Initialize an object
  constructor(name, grade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
  }

  //Declare a method
  showAlltheGrades() {
    document.writeln(this.name + ", " + this.grade + "<br>");
  } //End method

} //End class


//Bubblesort function
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  //loop length
  const loop = arr.length;

  //loop for loop length
  for (let i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < loop; j++) { //loop to cycle through array items
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) { //Compare adjacent items eg. 12 and 54
        let temp = arr[j]; //Temp takes 54
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; //arr[j+1] now takes 54 and arr[j] takes 23
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
    document.writeln(arr + "<br>");
  }
  return arr;
}


//function to get student info
function getStudentInfo(arr) {
  let i = 0;
  const arrLength = arr.length;
  while (i <= arrLength) {
    arr[i].name = prompt("Enter student name: ");
    arr[i].grade = parseInt(prompt("Enter student grade: "));
    i++;
    if (arr.name === "???") {
      break;
    }
  }
}

//Students array that holds name and grade
let students = [];

//Call functions
getStudentInfo(students);
bubbleSort(students);

//Show all students names and grades
for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  students[i].showAlltheGrades(); //Calls method
}
```

Comment: Is arr.length === 0 initially?

Comment: `if (arr.name === "???") {` You might have forgotten to include the element index

Answer (score 1):

`arrLength == 0`. After you increment `i`, `i <= 0` will no longer be true, to the loop ends.

There's no need for that test in the loop. You want to loop until the user enters `???`, so use `while (true)` to loop with no condition, and then exit the loop with `break`.

Also, you need to create an object in `arr[i]`, you can't just assign to properties of a nonexistent element.

```js
class Student {
  //Initialize an object
  constructor(name, grade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
  }

  //Declare a method
  showAlltheGrades() {
    document.writeln(this.name + ", " + this.grade + "<br>");
  } //End method

} //End class


//Bubblesort function
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  //loop length
  const loop = arr.length;

  //loop for loop length
  for (let i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < loop; j++) { //loop to cycle through array items
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) { //Compare adjacent items eg. 12 and 54
        let temp = arr[j]; //Temp takes 54
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; //arr[j+1] now takes 54 and arr[j] takes 23
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
    document.writeln(arr + "<br>");
  }
  return arr;
}


//function to get student info
function getStudentInfo(arr) {
  while (true) {
    let name = prompt("Enter student name: ");
    if (name == "???") {
      break;
    }
    let grade = parseInt(prompt("Enter student grade: "));
    arr.push(new Student(name, grade));
  }
}

//Students array that holds name and grade
let students = [];

//Call functions
getStudentInfo(students);
bubbleSort(students);

//Show all students names and grades
for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  students[i].showAlltheGrades(); //Calls method
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this line to me? What exactly does ```new Student(name, grade)``` do?

Comment: That's how you create objects in a class `Student()`. If you're learning classes, didn't they explain that?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `getStudentInfo()` you're passing in `students` which is an empty array. Its length is `0`. Then you enter your loop.  The first time, both `i` and `arrLength` are zero so it fires. But it stops after the first prompt because there is no such thing as `arr[0]`, since you still haven't yet populated the array with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `while` loop, you can use a `forEach` loop. In your loop, it breaks out if the user types `???`. Since we cannot break out of `forEach` loops, we can instead write a variable to see if we need to quit. More info on `forEach` loops [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
class Student {
  //Initialize an object
  constructor(name, grade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
  }

  //Declare a method
  showAlltheGrades() {
    document.writeln(this.name + ", " + this.grade + "<br>");
  } //End method

} //End class


//Bubblesort function
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  //loop length
  const loop = arr.length;

  //loop for loop length
  for (let i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < loop; j++) { //loop to cycle through array items
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) { //Compare adjacent items eg. 12 and 54
        let temp = arr[j]; //Temp takes 54
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; //arr[j+1] now takes 54 and arr[j] takes 23
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
    document.writeln(arr + "<br>");
  }
  return arr;
}


//function to get student info
function getStudentInfo(arr) {
  let i = 0;
  const arrLength = arr.length;
  while (i <= arrLength) {
    arr[i].name = prompt("Enter student name: ");
    arr[i].grade = parseInt(prompt("Enter student grade: "));
    i++;
    if (arr.name === "???") {
      break;
    }
  }
  let getOut = false; //since you can't break out of forEach loops
  arr.forEach(item=>{
    if (getOut) return;
    item.name = prompt("Enter student name: ");
    arr[i].grade = parseInt(prompt("Enter student grade: "));
    if (arr.name === "???") {
      getOut = true;
    }
  });
}

//Students array that holds name and grade
let students = [];

//Call functions
getStudentInfo(students);
bubbleSort(students);

//Show all students names and grades
for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  students[i].showAlltheGrades(); //Calls method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for each student file and push() that onto an array, if it doesn't exist.

```js
    function getStudentInfo(arr){
      i = 0;
      const arrLength = arr.length;
      while (true) {
        ob = new Object;
        ob.name = prompt("Enter student name: ");
        if(!ob.name) break;
        ob.grade = parseInt(prompt("Enter student grade: "));
        arr.push(ob);
      }
    }

    arr=new Array();
    getStudentInfo(arr);
    output = JSON.stringify(arr);

    document.write(output);
```